# Remove a character between two words in regex java

Tags: java, regex, string

I need to remove SPACE between `[^ ]` and `[^ ]`.

Example:

**My Input:** `PATRICK   GOOD MAN`

**Expected Output:** `PATRICK   GOODMAN`.

---

I tried using these regex expression `[^A-Z ]|[^ ]( )[^ ]` , `[^A-Z {3}]` and this `[^A-Z( {3})]`, but these solution are not conform with Regex Java.

Can anyone help me with this?

P.S.: I am using **Java 1.11**

Comment: Do you mean `replaceAll("(?<=\\S)\\s(?=\\S)","")`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this regex `(?<=\\S)\\s(?=\\S)` doesn't work: https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html#ad-output

Comment: The regex I suggested is `(?<=\S)\s(?=\S)`. `s.replaceAll("(?<=\\S)\\s(?=\\S)","")` is the code I suggested.

Comment: It's working! Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```java
(?<=\S)\s(?=\S)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wm9jCO/1). *Details*:

- `(?<=\S)` - a positive lookbehind that requires a non-whitespace char to appear immediately to the left of the current location
- `\s` - a whitespace
- `(?=\S)` - a positive lookahead that requires a non-whitespace char to appear immediately to the right of the current location.

In Java, use

```java
String result = text.replaceAll("(?<=\\S)\\s(?=\\S)","");
```

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/2NmNXP).